# call function of 'undefined' object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a JS question, I can't seem to be able to call a method. I'm using this dragger script: http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/

To use it I gotta define it like this:

```
new Dragdealer('just-a-slider', {
   animationCallback: function(x, y) {
      $('#just-a-slider .value').text(Math.round(x * 100));
   }
});
```

The documentation says:

> setValue(x, y, snap=false) Set the value of a Dragdealer instance
>   programatically. The 3rd parameter allows to snap the handle directly
>   to the desired value, without any sliding transition.

I tried:

```
var dragdealer_instance = new Dragdealer('just-a-slider', {
   animationCallback: function(x, y) {
      $('#just-a-slider .value').text(Math.round(x * 100));
   }
});
dragdealer_instance.setValue(10, 1);
```

but it says that the dragdealer_instance is undefined.. how can I call that function?

Comment: can you show your html too please

Comment: Can't reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/a8chxj62/ Can you provide exact error message and stack ?